# How to implement Speech to text in MAUI?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, maui, text-to-speech

I want to convert speech into text in .Net MAUI. I search for same I did not get solution for it.

Please let me know how to implement it.

I follow this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/speech-recognition-in-dotnet-maui-with-community-toolkit/

Code is as follow:

> 

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
        var isGranted = await SpeechToText.Default.RequestPermissions(cancellationToken);
        if (!isGranted)
        {
            await Toast.Make("Permission not granted").Show(CancellationToken.None);
            return;
        }
        var recognitionResult = await SpeechToText.Default.ListenAsync(
                                            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("uk-ua"),
                                            new Progress(partialText =>
                                            {
                                                RecognitionText += partialText + " ";
                                            }), cancellationToken);
        if (recognitionResult.IsSuccessful)
        {
           string RecognitionText = recognitionResult.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            await Toast.Make(recognitionResult.Exception?.Message ?? "Unable to recognize speech").Show(CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
```

Error as in below image

[image]

Please share your suggestion, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error tells you **exactly** what's wrong. You're missing the `<T>` param. E.g.: `new Progress<int>...`

Comment: Please don't just reask a question. If you would have checked the comments on your older question, you would have an answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code in the Microsoft document about [SpeechToText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/speech-to-text?tabs=android).

Here is the code an be used as follows in C#:

```
async Task Listen(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var isGranted = await speechToText.RequestPermissions(cancellationToken);
    if (!isGranted)
    {
        await Toast.Make("Permission not granted").Show(CancellationToken.None);
        return;
    }

    var recognitionResult = await speechToText.ListenAsync(
                                        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Language),
                                        new Progress<string>(partialText =>
                                        {
                                            RecognitionText += partialText + " ";
                                        }), cancellationToken);

    if (recognitionResult.IsSuccessful)
    {
        RecognitionText = recognitionResult.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        await Toast.Make(recognitionResult.Exception?.Message ?? "Unable to recognize speech").Show(CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```